# Seeking clarification on inline namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, inline-namespaces

In [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces), the following text is found:

> Each member of an inline namespace can be partially specialized ,
>   explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized as if it were a
>   member of the enclosing namespace.
>
> Note: the rule about specializations allows library versioning:
>   different implementations of a library template may be defined in
>   different inline namespaces, while still allowing the user to extend
>   the parent namespace with an explicit specialization of the primary
>   template.

What do these statements imply? Can someone explain by means of a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a stupid example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    inline namespace v1 {
        template <typename T>
        void bar(T t) {
            (void) t;
            std::cout << "Generic bar\n";
        }
    }

    template <>
    void bar<int>(int v) {
        (void) v;
        std::cout << "Specialized bar\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    foo::bar(12);
    foo::v1::bar(12);
    foo::bar(12.0);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this, you'll get the following output:

```
Specialized bar
Specialized bar
Generic bar
```

This is because calling `foo::bar` with an `int` is specialized in `foo`, even though the default implementation exists in `foo::v1`.

This example is useless, but consider a scenario where you wanted to specialize a `template` function or `class` in an external library (including the stl).  You don't know if `vector` is a member of `std` or `std::cxx11` (libc++ uses `std::__1` for many things).  Since an `inline namespace` is a way to provide versioning at the API level (e.g., you change your `inline namespace` to `v2` and leave `v1` alone), this lets end-users specialize without knowing the details of the `inline`d `namespace`s.